# AWS CloudWatch free disk space for all instances using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

We are using the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to upload instance metrics to CloudWatch. I've been able to create a boto3 script to create CloudWatch alarms for CPU Utilization greater than 85% and need to get the 'LogicalDisk % Free Space' for all the instance volumes. Another post showed _Total can be used for the SSM agent but it doesn't work for the metrics reported by CWAgent. The following code is what I used to create an alarm for a single volume on a single instance, then modified it to loop through all instances.

What can I do to create a CloudWatch alarm for 'LogicalDisk % Free Space' that has less than or equal to 15% free space for all the instance volumes?

```
import boto3, sys

# This script requires an AWS profile name to be passed to it
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("A profile parameter is required.")
    profile = input("Enter a profile name: ")
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=profile)
else:
    profile = (sys.argv[1])
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=sys.argv[1])

# Create EC2 resource
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Getting all running instances
instances = ec2.instances.all()

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

for i in instances:
    i_name = "unnamed"
    for tag in i.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == "Name":
            i_name = tag['Value']
    print(i_name, i.id)

    # Create alarm
    cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
        AlarmName = i_name + "-(" + i.id + ")-" + "Disk-Utilization-85-Pct",
        ComparisonOperator = 'LessThanOrEqualToThreshold',
        EvaluationPeriods = 10,
        MetricName = 'LogicalDisk % Free Space',
        Namespace = 'CWAgent',
        Period = 60,
        Statistic = 'Average',
        Threshold = 15.0,
        ActionsEnabled = False,
        AlarmDescription = 'Alarm when there is 15% disk space or less',
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'InstanceId',
                'Value': id,
                'Name': 'instance',
                'Value': '_Total'
            },
        ],
        Unit = 'Seconds',
        TreatMissingData = 'notBreaching'
    )
```

Comment: The Dimensions section of the code is where I need assistance. I am uncertain what to use for the value of the instance key pair.

`Dimensions = [
 {
  'Name': 'InstanceId',
  'Value': id,
  'Name': 'instance',
  'Value': '_Total'
 },
]`
The '_Total' value isn't working as a wildcard to create an alarm for each volume of the instance. This script is being used for CWAgent metrics in CloudWatch.

Comment: I now have boto3 code that will access the 5 CWAgent Dimensions in JSON output. I would to be able to parse the JSON into sets of data for each volume an instance has. Every volume creates another data set (JSON) Each data set needs variables to be created for all 5 dimensions; at least instance and InstanceId. The variables will be used to create CloudWatch alarms for each volume.
 `Dimensions=[{'Name': 'instance'}, {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': a}, {'Name': 'ImageId'}, Name': 'objectname'}, {'Name': 'InstanceType'}`
        ]`

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions piece of code follows below for your reference, give a try.

```
"dimensions": [
            {
                "value": "_Total",
                "name": "instance"
            },
            {
                "value": "AHS01IPKI02T",
                "name": "host"
            },
            {
                "value": "Processor",
                "name": "objectname"
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).